# Android Activity abruptly getting closed

Tags: android, android-activity, chromium

I have a Activity in my application which has a webview as a view element.
In my webview I am loading a webpage and on clicking a link on this webpage I am redirected to another webpage.
However, once this webpage loads my activity is destroyed abruptly without any error or exception. Is there any way to track who is destroying the activity.
The only error logs I can see are shown below:

```
15:01:03.608: I/chromium(2584): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "resetting timeouts due to ajax request..."
15:01:03.609: I/chromium(2584): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "timeouts reset...",
```

Do they even make any difference?

Comment: Post your code what you done so far

Comment: If your app is crashing, there must be an error log.

Comment: My app is not crashing. Only the activity destroys.